# iOS Developer: the network Api Issue. How to put a image data in a dictionary? How to persuade the server?

Tags: ios, objective-c

iOS develop:  to upload images with POST network request.

I use AFN .Usually we configurate the HTTP headers and put the image data in the HTTP body.

After a lot googling , still not aware of it.

The server, JAVA, demands the image data shall be uploaded with a key.

I met a problem.

[image]

```
 [formData appendPartWithFileData: imageData name: @"photoFile" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@.jpeg",dateString,@(idx)] mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
//the name is the key to the server.
```

So I set the **name**, after the server's confirming , I uploaded the image data successfully.

**But AFN Error:**

> domain: @"com.alamofire.error.serialization.response"

I tried to fix it, and failed.

I handled the types in the **AFN** , but it does not work.

```
 @implementation AFJSONResponseSerializer
 self.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript",@"text/html", nil];
```

I doesn't know much of the server, and has been confused by the Java Engineer.

I feel like the **key** (photoFile) has been set explicitly.

PS: How to persuade the the Java Engineer, uploading images without key-value.

Here is the code:

```
+ (void)startMultiPartUploadTaskWithURL:(NSString *)url
                           imagesArray:(NSArray *)images
                     parameterOfimages:(NSString *)parameter
                        parametersDict:(NSDictionary *)parameters
                      compressionRatio:(float)ratio
                          succeedBlock:(void(^)(id response, NSError *error ))succeedBlock
                           failedBlock:(void(^)(id response, NSError *error ))failedBlock
                   uploadProgressBlock:(void (^)(float, long long, long long))uploadProgressBlock{

    AFHTTPRequestSerializer * requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer ];

    [requestSerializer setValue: @"Bearer 933d16fa-8aa8-4c48-a250-62f905276ab7"  forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [requestSerializer setValue: @"b6862a23-f60c-4551-adcd-efa845d1511a"  forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Request-ID"];

    requestSerializer.timeoutInterval = 120.f;
    NSMutableURLRequest * request = [requestSerializer  multipartFormRequestWithMethod: @"POST" URLString: url parameters: parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData>  _Nonnull formData) {
        if (images.count > 0) {
            //generate the image's name
            NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
            NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
            [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmmss"];
            NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
            [images enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIImage *image, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
                NSData *imageData;
                //adjust the imageData size
                imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,ratio);
                CGFloat sizeOriginKB = imageData.length / 1024.0;
                CGFloat resizeRate = ratio/2.0;
                //adjust the imageData size , <250Kb
                while (sizeOriginKB > 250 && resizeRate > 0.01) {
                    imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,resizeRate);
                    sizeOriginKB = imageData.length / 1024.0;
                    resizeRate = resizeRate/2.0;
                }
                [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name: @"photoFile" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@.jpeg",dateString,@(idx)] mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
            }];
        }
    } error: nil ];
    NSURLSessionUploadTask * uploadTask;
    AFURLSessionManager * manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration: [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    uploadTask = [manager uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest: request progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {} completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        succeedBlock(responseObject, nil );
        failedBlock(nil, error);
        //responseObject;
        //error;
    } ];
    [uploadTask resume ];
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't persuade the Java Engineer but just fix this in iOS, it isn't too hard. But for us to help, we need much more iOS code. For example, the whole API call in Objective-C.

Comment: Updated. Awesome of you. No more spam words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AFN Error indicates: wrong request for "text/plain".

It's OK after communicating with the server to response JSON not a String.